Foreign Key Mismatch when inserting data in SQLite
I've been trying to insert data in a new table I created with a foreign key referencing another table, but it doesn't seem to work, even when I used the same thing in another table.
When I try, for example, Insert into Chapters(video_id) VALUES (470114);, with a unique id that exists in Videos, the only error that shows is the vague 'foreign key mismatch - "Chapters" referencing "Videos"'
CREATE TABLE "Videos" (
    [id] INTEGER, 
    [title] text NOT NULL, 
    [yr] INT NOT NULL, 
    [runtime] INT NOT NULL, 
    [descp] text NULL, 
    [cats] text NOT NULL, 
    [creators] text NOT NULL, 
    [creator_roles] text NULL, 
    [thumbnail] BLOB NOT NULL DEFAULT (x''), 
    [file_location] text NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE "Chapters" ( 
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    video_id INTEGER, 
    chapter_number INTEGER, 
    name TEXT, 
    runtime INTEGER, 
    FOREIGN KEY (video_id) REFERENCES "Videos"(id) )

The part I don't really get is that there is another table, "Roles", that works quite alright and has the same foreign key as Chapters would:
CREATE TABLE "Roles" ( 
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    vd_id INTEGER, 
    person_id INTEGER, 
    person_role TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (vd_id) REFERENCES "Videos"(id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES "Person"(id) )

If there is a constraint in SQLite that prevents having two or more tables referencing the same column in another table, I'm not aware of it. This is a puzzle I really can't understand. Thanks for the help!

The reason for the error is the Videos.id does not have a UNIQUE constraint (either by itself, or as a Primary Key). This is required. Adding such an index will make your example work. I'd suggest to notice that sqlite does not enforce NOT NULL on PRIMARY KEY-columns, which you should also fix. With respect to Roles, I suspect you either left vd_id as NULL (there is no example given), or you are not using the definition shown here.

In your videos table, id needs to be INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, not just INTEGER. Foreign keys in SQLite need a primary key for the relationship to work.

Can't comment so, I'll be answering instead.
tl;dr: Your Videos table needs to declare the id as PRIMARY KEY or as a UNIQUE key, alternatively you can disable foreign keys (not recommended)
After a quick google search I found this StackOverflow answer.
To quote the answer:

From Required and Suggested Database Indexes:
Usually, the parent key of a foreign key constraint is the primary key of the parent table. If they are not the primary key, then the parent key columns must be collectively subject to a UNIQUE constraint or have a UNIQUE index.

They even provide a demo.
Here is my demo.
If you remove the PRIMARY KEY you will see your error.

Please do not post links (even with quotes) to other SO answers as new answers; flag the question as a possible duplicate instead.
